# How can i capture the UDP packet and find the TTL Values from the packet using python

Tags: python

HI

I want to capture the UDP packets by joining to the Multicast group. after the receving the packet i want to check for the TTL value from that UDP packet. How can i achieve this by using python ?

The Sammple code as mentioned below:
here 
**rec_port** is any port which i had used to bind; eg: 9180
**rec_hostname** is any multicast group which i had joined;eg:239.2.2.2

```
 #! /usr/bin/env python
    .........
    ............
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(("", rec_port))
    mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(rec_hostname), socket.INADDR_ANY)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

    total_length = 0
    while True:
            print "Waiting for the packets, if no packets recevied by 10 seconds, than i will exit"
            sock.settimeout(10)
            data , address = sock.recvfrom(2048)
            if len(data) > 1:
                                    total_length=total_length + len(data)
                                    print "Data is:", data
                                    print "Length of data received is:", len(data)
                                    print "Packet recevied from :", address[0]
                                    print "Total Packet size:", total_length
            else:
                    break
    sock.close()
    print "Total Packet size:", total_length
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [this](http://pycap.sourceforge.net/) python wrapper. If it doesn't satisfy you can wrap [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) yourself.

**In response to unwind:** You don't have to act "promiscious" with libpcap, you can inject and snoop valid traffic -- i.e., meant for your NIC.

**Edit:** Read this tutorial on [pcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.htm) to figure out how to isolate the ttl field.

Comment: I'm using python 2.3 version, I guess in this version i cant use the pcap or libpcap module/lib . This is not supported. I'm able to bind to the multicast group. But how can i read the TTL value from the packet recevied?

Comment: The TTL value is in the IP header part of the packet, this is generally not available to user space programs so joining the multicast group won't help -- you do need libpcap or something similar. The pycap page says they do support 2.3 though?

Comment: If it really won't work with pycap, another (but messier) option is to call `tcpdump` using `os.popen` and parse its output...

Comment: I'm trying to use python to automate my manual verfication steps used in testing of my component. If at all i want to use the libpcap or something like that than how can i implement these libpcap in my script?

Comment: you need to wrap the c code and make it callable from python. see http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html

Answer (score 0):

in a comment, you told us that you are able to join the multicast group.

now you can use `getsockopt()`, specify `IPPROTO_IP` for the level parameter and `IP_MULTICAST_TTL` for the option, to get the TTL value which is written to outgoing packets.

Comment: that's why i specified "outgoing packets" in my reply.

Comment: Yes i want for incoming packet. 
i'd this similar problem while sending the data to a multicast group. i had resolved it by the way Plisson have detailed.